# Angular 2 set Div maxlength

Tags: html, angular, copy-paste

I am using Angular 2 with TypeScript. I have to put one validation on "Div". I have to set maxlength for Div to 100 also in case of copy-paste the text Div text length should not exceed from 100.

Any suggestion would be appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: what does *set maxlength for Div* mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
```

does not have a maxlength attribute.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Div

```
<input>
```

Does.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Comment: #jriver27, your previous answer helped for me.